# Client Authentication: Cannot find the certificate in either the LocalMachine store or the CurrentUser store

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api

- I have imported the pfx file into chrome.
- And when I run the web API locally on visual studio and test using
  Postman everything works fine.
- But when I host the API on IIS 8.5, I get this error in the network
  trace.
- I have also imported the pfx on mmc under Personal store for both
  local Machine and Current User.
- The client cert is stored in a p12 file, which our program opens
  directly by file path (ie: not from Windows Certificate Store).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by granting my App pool permission to Machine keys folder.

```
icacls C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys /grant "IIS AppPool\xyz":(CI)(OI)(F)
```

CI- container inherit - subordinate containers will inherit this permission

OI- object inherit - subordinate files will inherit this permission

F -Full Control